# Composer installation issue on windows 8.1

Tags: php, windows, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to download laravel project via composer on microsoft windows 8.1.
But I am unable to download because I receive **APPDATA COMPOSER_HOME** environment variable issue for this I uninstall the composer from my system and try to re install the latest version of composer on windows 8.1 but I still receiving following error

> The APPDATA or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly

How to solve this problem? I also searched on google but no useful solution found.

Comment: How did you install composer? using the installer or manually?

Comment: @Latheesan I am installing composer through exe file

Comment: this might help: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4789

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, then it would be better to install the composer using their setup:
https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe

This should take care of installing and setting the paths correctly. If you've installed it manually, run this command to set the path before using composer:

```
Set COMPOSER_HOME="C:\path\to\where\composer\installed"
```

Comment: I am trying to install composer via composer-setup.exe file while installing I am receving this error which I mention above

Comment: Are you running the installer as admin?

Comment: Take a look at this detailed guide: http://webdevzoom.com/how-to-install-composer-on-windows/

Comment: I am receiving this error on step 5 according to you duided link

Answer (score 0):

try this command bro in your cmd prompt.

```
SET COMPOSER_HOME="C:\path\to\composer"
composer self-update
```